# warnings about mystery interfaces in C# projects

Tags: c#, interface, warnings, idispatch, iunknown

Every time I build my C# Solution, I get a handful of warnings about interfaces that I've never seen or written.  I tried Googling for some of them, but get no hits.  Could these possibly be buried in an assembly I'm referencing?  If so, is there any way to make these warnings go away?

> Interface 'IAlertable' is marked as [dual], but does not derive from IDispatch. It will be converted as an IUnknown-derived interface.
>
> Interface 'ICustomizationPermissionsReports' is marked as [dual], but does not derive from IDispatch. It will be converted as an IUnknown-derived interface.
>
> Interface 'IAlertable2' is marked as [dual], but does not derive from IDispatch. It will be converted as an IUnknown-derived interface.

Comment: Do you have the **Register for COM interop** setting checked in the project settings?

Comment: Did you reference any COM dlls?  You get these warnings when referenced COM components are not defined correctly.

Comment: @Chaos:  in the Build section of the properties on my project, "Register for COM interop" is not checked and it's actually disabled.

Answer (score 6):

They must come form a COM assembly you are referencing. You could try to find out which one. It looks like the wrapper code was written/generated incorrectly.

And Visual Studio does have a "suppress warnings: " text box but I am at a loss as to what to type there.
Project Properties, Build

Answer (score 4):

These are interfaces to HP Quality Center OTA-API "Interop.TDAPIOLELib", an ActiveX COM Type Library.
Check your references.